# Calculating a vector raster intersection in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, carto

I am using CartoDB and trying to calculate the total population (in raster format in popcount) within a specified distance to a line (vector data in mytable). The population data is at about 5km resolution. The approach I took was to vectorize the raster data around the line using ST_DumpAsPolygons, then to Sum() up all of these raster values.

```
SELECT filter,round(Sum((gv).val)) FROM 
(
  SELECT provider, ST_DumpAsPolygons(ST_Clip(rast, 1, mytable.the_geom, true)) AS gv 
  FROM popcount, mytable
  WHERE ST_Intersects(rast, mytable.the_geom)
) AS foo GROUP BY foo.filter ORDER BY round DESC
```

The problem with this approach is that I seem to double count populations that are close to several lines.

Is there a better way to calculate a vector-raster intersection, or is there a modification I can make to this query to avoid double counting?

Answer (score 1):

To avoid double-counting you need to select a single line for each raster area. You can do that using KNN index, with something like this:

select a.id as a, l.id as l from areas a, lines l where l.id = ( select id from lines order by g <-> a.g limit 1 );

The "lines" table would be your "mytable".

The "area" table you'll need to construct (on the fly or, better, creating an intermediate table). You could use vector-raster intersection for that: http://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_Intersection.html